# How to extend tap to handle continuous touches?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using the code below to fire a projectile (in a Sprite Kit based game) when the screen is "tapped", this all works fine. However I want to expand this so that handleTap is repeatedly called whilst the user "touches and holds down on the screen" Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
// INITIAL SETUP
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

.

```
// WHEN TAPPED
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self setupAndFireProjectile];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer) instead:

```
// INITIAL SETUP
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

.

```
// WHEN TAPPED
- (void)handleTouch:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self setupAndFireProjectile];
}
```

or use [`UIResponder`'s](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     // Start shooting
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     // End shooting
}
```